# DataTables Multiple Tables from Multiple JSON Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I want to output two tables, each sourcing information from two separate arrays within the same JSON source, but for some reason my code doesn't work.

JSON Message:

```
{
  "Policies": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "id": "1",
      "score": "0"
    }
  ],
  "Services": [
    {
      "name": "B",
      "id": "2",
      "score": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<table id="policies-table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table id="services-table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var the_url = "www.example.com"

var columnsDef = [
    { data : "name" },
    { data : "id" },
    { data : "score" }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#policies-table').DataTable({
        ajax : {
        url : the_url,
        dataSrc: "Policies"
                },
        columns : columnsDef
}),

    $('#services-table').DataTable({
        ajax : {
        url : the_url,
        dataSrc: "Services"
                },
        columns : columnsDef
})
});
```

Comment: How are you passing the JSON to JS function? Also, simply writing "Policies" and "Services" won't help. Why don't you iterate over the JSON and based on the keys, populate the table?

Comment: I'm passing JSON through "the_url" variable. I didn't have to iterate over JSON when building a single table, so I don't think it would be any different when creating multiple tables. I thought that there would be some in-built DataTables functionality to do all this @prabodhprakash

Comment: Your code is correct, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/dz5gxtob/3/). Check whether your URL is correct or response from the script matches what you've posted.

Comment: I checked your example, changed my code accordingly and now it works! Thank you very very much @Gyrocode.com !

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating through your JSON variable. As prabodhprakash suggested, writing "Policies" and "Services" won't help either.

I suggest you to take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz5gxtob/2/)

You can initialize multiple datatables with the same syntax that you use for initializing a single one:

```
var json = {
  "Policies": [{
    "name": "A",
    "id": "1",
    "score": "0"
  }],
  "Services": [{
    "name": "B",
    "id": "2",
    "score": "0"
  }]
}


var policyTable = $("#policies-table").DataTable({
  "data" : (json.Policies),
  "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "score" }]
});

var serviceTable = $("#services-table").DataTable({
    "data" :(json.Services),
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "score" }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I read up more on it and change my javascript to the following:

Comment: `var policyTable = $("#policies-table").DataTable({
 ajax : {
        url : the_url,
  dataSrc: function (json) {
   json = JSON.parse(json);
   return json.data;
  },
  "data": (json.data.Policies),
  "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "score" }]
}); `